# TFTP Timing Out on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, timeout, tftp

I'm running a Windows 7 PC with VMware installed which has my Ubuntu (10.04 Lucid Lynx).
I recently installed a DHCP server and TFTP (Xinet tftpd) using [these](http://www.davidsudjiman.info/2006/03/27/installing-and-setting-tftpd-in-ubuntu/) instructions. I've mapped a network drive so that my Windows has access to all the files in my VM through a 192.x.x.x IP address.
I'm trying to throw some custom firmware onto a router. The router has its own built-in TFTP utility that will download the image. It successfully manages to do everything but it is slow because it writes it to flash memory. There is another method that is much quicker because it writes to RAM directly but it must use the TFTP server in Ubuntu.
The issue I'm facing is that the Ubuntu TFTP transfer seems to be timing out. The transfer starts but never goes past ~60%. Here's my /etc/xinetd.d/tftp file (similar to a known working config):

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = -s /home/user/tftp/
disable         = no
cps             = 300 2
per_source      = 60
}
```

I've done some searching but can't find any parameters for this file to control timeout time or number of retries. The last two arguments (cps, per_source) and completely alien to me (can anyone explain).
I have a few possible solutions but the easiest would be to get this TFTP server working. Can anyone help? Either with a timeout configuration or maybe even recommend a different TFTP server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Linux expert, but I use the `server_args` parameter (http://linux.die.net/man/5/xinetd.conf) to pass parameters to the TFTP process. tftpd has a `--timeout` parameter (http://linux.die.net/man/8/tftpd). You might try something like

```
service tftp {
    [...]
    server_args = --timeout 10000 -s /home/user/tftp/

}
```